# how to access elements by path?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I am trying to parse with `BeautifulSoup` an awful HTML page to retrieve a few information. The code below:

```
import bs4

with open("smartradio.html") as f:
    html = f.read()

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html)
x = soup.find_all("div", class_="ue-alarm-status", playerid="43733")
print(x)
```

extracts the fragments I would like to analyze further:

```
[<div alarmid="f319e1fb" class="ue-alarm-status" playerid="43733">
<div>
<div class="ue-alarm-edit ue-link">Réveil 1:            </div>
<div>allumé</div>
<div>7:00</div>
</div>
<div>
<div class="ue-alarm-dow">Lu, Ma, Me, Je, Ve            </div>
<div class="ue-alarm-delete ue-link">Supprimer</div>
</div>
</div>, <div alarmid="ea510709" class="ue-alarm-status" playerid="43733">
<div>
<div class="ue-alarm-edit ue-link">Réveil 2:            </div>
<div>allumé</div>
<div>7:30</div>
</div>
<div>
<div class="ue-alarm-dow">Sa            </div>
<div class="ue-alarm-delete ue-link">Supprimer</div>
</div>
</div>]
```

I am interested in retrieving:

- the hour (line 5 and 14)
- the string (days in French) under `<div class="ue-alarm-dow">`

I believe that for the days it is enough to repeat a `find()` or `find_all()`. I am mentioning that because while it grabs the right information, I am not sure that this is the right way to parse the file with BeautifulSoup (but at least it works):

```
for y in x:
    z = y.find("div", class_="ue-alarm-dow")
    print(z.text)
# output:
# Lu, Ma, Me, Je, Ve            
# Sa
```

I do not know how to get to the hour, though. Is there a way to navigate the tree by path (in the sense that I know that the hour is under the second `<div>`, three `<div>` deep)? Or should I do it differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also rely on the `allumé` text and get [the next sibling `div` element](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-sibling-and-previous-sibling):

```
y.find('div', text=u'allumé').find_next_sibling('div').text
```

or, in a similar manner, relying on the `class` of the previous `div`:

```
y.find('div', class_='ue-alarm-edit').find_next_siblings('div')[1].text
```

or, using [regular expressions](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-regular-expression):

```
y.find('div', text=re.compile(r'\d+:\d+')).text
```

or, just get the `div` by index:

```
y.find_all('div')[4].text
```